# Get iTunes cover art path by Persistent ID in .itc2 file

Tags: xml, image, itunes

I'm trying to dump album artwork from iTunes ".ITC2" files. Witch I can do. But before I try and dump the image, I need to make note of what Album/Track/Artist (any of the three) that it corresponds to. Has anyone found out if they changed the way the cache files are named? Because, with a file name of "0FBCBB4BA8C7828A-9EB924E27638E4A5.itc2" "0FBCBB4BA8C7828A" is in fact my Library ID but "9EB924E27638E4A5" is nowhere to be found in my Library's XML file. Can someone explain to me how to correlate itc2 files with tracks that are located in the XML file.

Get iTunes cover art path by Persistent ID in .itc2 file.

This .itc2 file is combination of [Library Persistent ID - Track Persistent ID].itc2
these both are in iTunes Music Library.xml

Library Persistent ID0FBCBB4BA8C7828A

Persistent ID--------------- 
Collection of itc2 files.
0FBCBB4BA8C7828A-9EB924E27638E4A5.itc2 (I get list of all itc2 file by reading Subdirectories)

but now after iTunes update i can't find 9EB924E27638E4A5 (Track Persistent ID) in xml ,
which is in 
Persistent ID---------------

but before iTunes 12 is exist in xml and i can read it as cover art.